# Two year old starting creche, completely hyper when he comes home

Tags: toddler, daycare

Our son (2 years & 9 months old) is starting creche, we've had some "introduction days" where we drop him in for a few hours each day to become accustomed to the change.

Normally he's an energetic - but NOT hyperactive - child, he rarely sits for long, always on the go. We do lots of activities together, he especially enjoys the messy parts of baking and loves to eat the food he helped prepare.

However for the last few days he's come home from creche absolutely hyper, bouncing off the walls, and today completely sabotaged a cooking task we were doing. After creche he no longer seems able to listen, constantly grabs anything & everything he can reach.

It's exhausting, and worrying.

He's been dropped in over the last four working days, lengthening the stay each time. This new behavior is more pronounced the longer he stays.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?
I'm fairly sure this is a temporary change until he settles into his new routine, but obviously the fear is this won't go away.

So, should I worry, is it a watch and wait sort of thing, or will this just go away and we'll get our well behaved little boy back soon?

**Update**
It took 2 - 3 weeks but he settled down :)

Comment: What's happening at the creche? Are they giving him green cordial?

Comment: Is there anything changing about his sleep habits right now? Hyperactivity can be a huge cue to overtiredness. Is he dropping his nap simultaneously or on a new nap or nighttime schedule due to creche?

Comment: Over the last two months or so he's been dropping his afternoon naps, now he might have a nap once a week or so. Otherwise there's no changes, he's going down a little earlier than before, but he's sleeping better on the whole. So no, I don't think its a sleep issue :)

Comment: What is "creche"?

Comment: Da01: "creche" is Europe what "Day Care" is to America, the place preschoolers go while their parents work :)

Comment: Could be bad influence form another kid, if your kid follows another kid around that is acting just like this, he might start that kind of behavior. It is a possibility.

Answer (score 3):

We have a boy about the same age who has the same behavior when he doesn't do enough physical activities during the day. At the creche, does your son do enough running around & playing ? Because if your son doesn't spend his energy during the day, he will be doing it at night.

Comment: Good point, I seriously doubt he's as active in there as he is at home.

Comment: Or, on the contrary, hyperactivity could also be a sign of overtiredness - depends on the child. Just try and observe what makes most sense.